# SwiftUI Button doesn't work in UIHostingController

Tags: ios, swiftui, uikit

I have a SwiftUI View that I am embedding in an existing UIViewController using UIHostingController. The SwiftUI view is simple, in fact I can reduce it down to this code and reproduce the issue:

```
let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: Button {
   print("tapped")
} label {
   Text("Tap")
}
```

The hostingController is added to my existing view controller as a child like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   view.addSubview(hostingController.view)
   // Code to set up autolayout constraints omitted.
   addChild(hostingController)
   hostingController.didMove(toParent: self)
}
```

The button is tappable in the canvas preview, but not in the simulator or on a real device. There are no gesture recognizers or other views covering the UIHostingController's view. I tried using `.onTapGesture(perform:)` instead of a Button but that didn't work either. To make things weirder, I can add a ScrollView as a subview of my SwiftUI and scrolling works. Why won't my button work?

Answer (score 8):

Apparently the issue was that the parent UIViewController was using a layer transform to animate itself onto the screen. This transform totally broke all SwiftUI taps gestures. When I changed the layer transform code to just change the view's frame everything worked.

The offending transform code looked like this:

```
view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -300, y: 0)

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
}
```

And I changed it to something like this:

```
view.frame.origin.x = view.frame.origin.x - 300

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
    self.view.frame.origin.x = self.view.frame.origin.x + 300
}
```

Comment: For your reference, it's not a matter of it *"all SwiftUI taps gestures"* ... your transform code changes the **visual appearance** but not the view hierarchy. So, at that point, your button is outside the bounds of its superview and you can no longer interact with it. This is the case regardless of UIKit or SwiftUI. So, as you've discovered, you want to change the frame of the view, not transform its appearance.

Comment: @DonMag I think you are misunderstanding my code. The view was being rendered offscreen and then animated onto the screen using `transform`. After the animation, which includes `self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity`, the view's rendered position goes back to normal, but the tap gesture recognizers for SwiftUI buttons did not.

Comment: It would help if you provided a [mre] so we can confirm what you've experienced. On the surface, applying a transform and then resetting it to `.identity` *shouldn't* affect the tap gestures.

Answer (score 5):

Had similar problem, but after not finished dismiss of `UIHostingConroller`. Here is my solution:

```
class SomePresentationController: UIPresentationController { 

// ...

override func dismissalTransitionDidEnd(_ completed: Bool) {
    super.dismissalTransitionDidEnd(completed)

    // Magic, that fixes not working buttons and gestures after non finished dismiss
    presentedViewController.view.bounds.origin.y = 0.1
    presentedViewController.view.bounds.origin.y = .zero
  }

// ...

}
```

Comment: This just fixed my issue with the same scenario. I've noticed there is no issue when using the default `UIPresentationController`, but only a custom one. I'm curious about how you found it.